# how to remove running custom script

Tags: iphone, scripting

hi i have followed this link(http://www.alexwhittemore.com/?p=398) a long time ago to install app onto my iphone to test however i failed to run it. now i have original apple membership and my app is finished. there is some custom script that was described in the article and it is still trying to run and causing error. my question is how to remove the custom script from running. it is step 7 where i think the error is in accessing custom entitlements please help

```
mkdir /Developer/iphoneentitlements401
cd /Developer/iphoneentitlements401
curl -O http://www.alexwhittemore.com/iphone/gen_entitlements.txt
mv gen_entitlements.txt gen_entitlements.py
chmod 777 gen_entitlements.py
```

My ERROR is Cannot access entitlement data en_entitlements.py Permission denied

Answer (score 0):

Put `sudo` before the command.

Comment: before the command which fails, I guess you don't have privileges to write to /Developer folder

Comment: haha finally found the custom script that runs and breaks my app in the targets folder. deleted the script and i am ready to hit next bug.!

Answer (score 0):

`sudo chmod 777 gen_entitlements.py`

then input your root password

Hope this helps.